# Getting service=git-receive-pack not found: did you run git update-server-info on the server?

Tags: git, github, git-branch

I tried to push my local changes to my branch on GitHub server. This was working like a charm before, when I used "Git Bash".
I configured  GitHub Windows app provided by Git (that purple cat icon which shows up on your Desktop when you install Git) to push my changes this time.
Thought GUI tool would be easier! When I tried "Publish" I saw a fatal-error msg.
Then I switched back to 'Git Bash' which worked fine with my previous commit to the same remote branch.

I typed following commands:

```
git add .gitignore
git add <<files>> # WORKED
git commit -m <commit desc> # WORKED
git push origin <mybranch> # errored out
```

I got the following error:

```
fatal: https://github.com/reponame/tree/<mybranch>//info/refs?service=git-receive-pack not found: 
did you run git update-server-info on the server?
```

I tried different things before posting this from similar posts.

- I edited PATH with .`.Git\bin,\Git\cmd ..Git\libexec\git-core`. This didn't help!
- Made sure `.git/config` has my branch URL
- Tried 'commit and push' from Eclipse. Same error.

Did installing/configuring Windows GitHub client app messed up something on my PC where I can't push my changes to remote repo anymore?

What else I should do to push my changes to repo branch? This is on Windows.

Comment: What is the output if you run `git remote -v`?

Comment: @BrianaSwift  I'm getting the following msg: 'origin https://github.com/reponame/tree/<mybranch>  (fetch)'  AND 'origin https://github.com/reponame/tree/<mybranch>  (push)'.   I even uninstalled Windows Github Desktop app and rebooted my machine and tried the push again. It didn't work. should I uninstall and reinstall git? I have git-Eclipse plug-in. Got the same error from there as well.

Comment: I wouldn't do that until it's the last resort. What version of Git do you have?

Comment: I finally got this resolved!!

Comment: @BrianaSwift, Finally I got this resolved!! I even uninstalled git and installed the latest version, but that didn't help. The actual issue was with the URL under .git/config where my "remote=origin" is referring to my "branch" instead of main URL. I changed it and my 'git push origin <branch>' worked without errors. Here is the content of my modified .git/config:  '[remote "origin"]
     url = https://github.com/reponame/nnn.git
     fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
     remote = origin
     merge = refs/heads/master'

Comment: Fantastic, I'm glad to hear it! :)

Comment: @BrianaSwift: I am facing the same issue and my git config file is also same as you have mentioned in your comment..any idea what can be the other issue then.

Answer (score 5):

I was getting the same error when git commit and push.
I browsed github for my file and tried to edit there, then I got to know I didn't had write access to the branch.
I tried committing with another ID, voila it works.
the error is misleading I believe.